# xpathGetString always returning empty string

Tags: java, docx4j

I am trying to read attribute from CustomXmlPart using xpathGetString

```
String abcd = lc_CustomXmlPart.xpathGetString( "/Contract/Currency[1]/@Code", "" );
System.out.println( abcd );
```

But it always returns empty string.

Xml looks like this:

```
<Contract xmlns="http://abc.123.cz" TypeCode="HO" IssueDate="2017-02-11">
    <Currency Code="EUR" Name="Default" PrintCode="€"></Currency>
</Contract>
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XML defines a default namespace (`xmlns`) and you're trying to access its nodes without specifying that namespace.

You can change your XPath to access nodes of any namespace :

- in XPath 1.0 : `/*[local-name()='Contract']/*[local-name()='Currency'][1]/@Code`
- in XPath 2.0 : `/*:Contract/*:Currency/@Code`

But it would be best to specify it :

```
String abcd = lc_CustomXmlPart.xpathGetString( "/abc:Contract/abc:Currency[1]/@Code", "xmlns:abc=\"http://abc.123.cz\"" );
```

I'm not sure about the exact syntax, check your API documentation ; what I'm sure about is that there is a way to specify prefix mappings which you'll be able to use in your XPath.

Note that there might be a way to specify a default namespace for your XPath query which would lead to the same result (selecting the node of the specific namespace) without having to modify your XPath.

Comment: @PiotrJanuszWijas You're welcome ! I remember some long sessions of head-scratching because of sneaky `xmlns` ;)

Comment: You might also be able to declare a namespace prefix in the xml (for example: xmlns:abc="http://abc.123.cz"), then use that prefix as per this answer.